# Obtaining exit code from schtasks

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to start a scheduled task from a Powershell script, like this:

```
schtasks /Run /TN "Test" > nul
```

I'm testing as I go, so I've set up the task to call a batch file that intentionally does not exist.

Once this happens, I see on the next line of code that the error level was 0, despite seeing 0x1 in the Task Scheduler's Last Run Result column.

In the console, I see

```
SUCCESS: Attempted to run the scheduled task "Test"
```

This looks to me as though it's considering the launch successful, and not waiting around to capture the error reported to Task Scheduler. (0x1)

How can I detect this error in Powershell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I seem to remember that `schtasks.exe` just instructs the the task scheduler to go run a job and immediately exists without waiting around. Hence it always  returning `0` unless the task itself can't be found (exit code: `1`) or something catastrophic happens (exit code: no idea).

If you want to get the *"Last Run Result"* you'll need to query the task, for example:

```
schtasks.exe /v /query /tn "A Real Task" /fo list
```

This will return the task details including its run status as a list of fields and values which will include the "Last Run Result".

To see more formatting options run:

```
schtasks.exe /query /?
```

So you could capture data about a task (in this case CSV formatted) by doing:

```
$taskinfo = schtasks.exe /query /tn "A Real Task" /FO CSV /V
```

...then process it in some way. Obviously you'd need to check the task's run status to make sure it's completed before reading the "Last Run Result".

Comment: For anyone seeing this on a search result, the "last run result" can be parsed into a variable by following the instructions at http://serverfault.com/questions/436720/is-it-possible-for-a-powershell-script-to-return-the-last-run-result-from-window

Comment: @iank - yes, I was going to add a bit about that, but it was way past my bedtime :)